# MSXML 6 is not listed in installed programs list of Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows-7, msxml, msxml6

I can see msxml6.dll file in C:\Windows\System32 and C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder but still this is not listed under Installed programs list.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: It is not an "installed program", it comes included with the operating system.  Along with *many* other executable files you find in those directories that are also not listed.

Comment: ok.. thanks @HansPassant.. So will it be fine if i remove earlier versions of MSXML installed manually.. I can see multiple versions installed in programs list, MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB954430), MSXML 4.0 SP2 (KB973688) , MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser , MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser (KB973685), MSXML 4.0 SP3 Parser (KB2758694)..

Comment: Version 4 was a special one, allowing programmers to deploy their own tested-and-known-to-work version so they don't depend on the OS version.  Which means that if you uninstall these then you'll very likely break *some* program that uses them.   That falls squarely into the "very dumb thing to do" category.   But hey, go ahead, the school of hard knocks is a place to learn too.

Answer (score 0):

MSXMl6 is part of Windows in the `Microsoft-Windows-SKU-Foundation-Package-sql` package afair since Vista.

[image]

This package is preinstalled and also includes MSXML3 as 64 and 32Bit Version. You only have to install MSXML4.